# Extract table from html using Java or Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html-table, html-content-extraction

I have a html files called page1.html, page2.html. In page1.html and page2.html I have a few content inside table element, now I want to extract those table contents and put it in new file called summary.html. I don't know jQuery, so how to do this from Java or Javascript. I know how to create html from Java/Javascript.

Comment: You can't really state that you don't know jQuery but are looking for a solution in JavaScript, can't you? ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure op is mixing up java and javascript

Answer (score 1):

If using Java, the best option I can think of is using [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/), a Java HTML parser library.

```
File input = new File("C:\\page1.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");

Element table = doc.getElementByTag("table");
Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");
for (Element row : rows) {
  String rowText = row.text();
}
```

Comment: thanks. how can i get specific table say table with id or class?

Comment: Code does not compile.